# C++: Overload global new/delete for multiple-DLL program

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, new-operator

- Multiple, implicitly-linked DLLs (owned and not owned)
- Multiple, explicitly-linked DLLs (owned and not owned)
- Would like to overload all instances of new/delete for owned DLLs
- Ideally, also would like to overload the implementation used by the CRT
- Purpose: track memory allocations to detect leaks, bad allocation patterns, fragmentation, ect.

Ideas:

1. **Statically compile overloads inside each owned DLL, with implementations calling out into a single DLL**. Is this undefined behavior? (*The behavior is undefined if more than one replacement is provided in the program for any of the replaceable allocation function*)
2. **Overload in one DLL, and export that implementation to other DLLs**. Would this not require a re declaration of the (implicitly) declared operators?

   I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  This looks like the problem the shard CRT DLL already solves.  Suspecting an XY issue with this question.

Comment: As usual - Why? And are these your own DLLs, so you could change `new x` into `new(my_arena) x`?

Comment: @RichardCritten We'd like to track memory usage for debugging purposes, identifying leaks, detecting bad allocation patterns, fragmentation, ect. The project is a few years old, and a few million lines of code. Also, in a perfect world, we'd also like to track allocations made by the CRT.

Comment: @BoPersson See above.

Comment: Hook malloc/alloc/realloc/VirtualAlloc etc. maybe?

Comment: MS give you a lot of help with this have a read of: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx

Comment: @VuVirt I didn't even know what a hook was until your comment. Looks perfect. Do you have any references on how to do this for Win32?

Comment: @Zed Check this for starters. I did a lot of hooking with it: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x-x-API-Hooking-Libra

Comment: @Zed, pls note that Detours-64 is not free (and available only by request). And Detour-32 is not free for commercial usage.